# Best way to install macOS on MSI laptop for Xcode?

Tags: macos, xcode

I need to install Xcode for iOS application developement. My laptop is MSI GP60 2OD-410X. I've looked on the Internet a little bit and there are many ways to install macOS on a normal computer and it also depends on the hardware and I'm confused because there are no so many tutorials for MSI laptop too.

So I wonder if there is anyone who has experience in this field can help me through or give me some advices?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about illegally copying software or violating a license agreement. OS X is only licensed for installation on Apple Mac hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way for you would be to download [VMWare](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0) and purchase an official Mac OS X Installation drive.

Or if you already have one, just use VMWare to install it. As this is a bit of a touchy subject (piracy, warranty, license violations), I won't get too much into how to acquire OS X. Use [Google](http://google.com/), it will probably help you out :)

Comment: Thank you, i found this: http://iatkos.me/ and it is not violated any licence right?